# How can I compare classes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I compare classes in Ruby or in other words how can I translate this Java code into Ruby?

```
Class<?> clazz = ...;
if (clazz == String.class) {
  ...
} else if (clazz == Integer.class) {
  ...
}
```

To clarify: I do *not* want to compare object instances or check if an object is an instance of a class.

**EDIT:** I do **not** want to compare object instances or check if an object is an instance of a class, i.e. `is_a?` and `kind_of?` don't help me.

Comment: I always thought `"abcdef".is_a?(String)` does the job. Maybe somebody else can chime in.

Comment: That `is_a?` checks if an object is of a certain type, but I want to check if two classes are equal.

Comment: According to the Ruby docs, `kind_of?` also works on instances, i.e. `String.kind_of?(String)` doesn't work.

Comment: You can just compare classes with the equality operator, but I have no idea why you're trying to "compare classes": `String == Integer # false` or `String == String #true`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The *literal* translation of your Java code would be something like

```
klass = ...

if klass == String
  ...
elsif klass == Integer
  ...
end
```

Or, more idiomatically

```
klass = ...

case
when klass == String
  ...
when klass == Integer
  ...
end
```

Or maybe

```
klass = ...

DISPATCH_TABLE = {
  String => -> { ... },
  Integer => -> { ... }
}

DISPATCH_TABLE[klass].()
```

However, Ruby is an object-oriented language, and in an object-oriented language this simply doesn't make sense. You would instead just write

```
class String
  def do_something
    ...
  end
end

class Integer
  def do_something
    ...
  end
end
```

and the language will perform the dispatching for you. This is called *polymorphism* and is supported by pretty much every object-oriented language and many non-object-oriented ones as well.

This particular transformation is one of the fundamental Refactorings described in Martin Fowler's book (p. 255), it is called the [*Replace Conditional With Polymorphism* Refactoring](http://Refactoring.Com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html).

The biggest problem with providing a sensible solution to your problem is that you don't tell us what the problem *is*. You only tell us what the *solution* is. Or, more precisely, you tell us what you *think* the solution is *in Java*, and you somehow expect that the solution in Ruby would be *exactly* 100% identical, even though the languages couldn't be more different.

To provide a good solution, we need to know the problem first. In other words: the most relevant parts of your question are the `…`s

Answer (score 5):

```
>> "foo".class == "bar".class
true
```

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, all classes objects are instances of the `Class` class. The names of classes are constants that refer to the instance. If you have a reference to the class object, you can compare it with the named constant for that class. So you could do:

```
if klass == String
  ...
elsif klass == Integer
  ...
end
```

The expression `String.class == Integer.class` would be true, since the class of both classes is, of course, `Class`.